# What is difference between HBox and VBox in SAPUI5?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

What is main difference between sap.m.HBox and sap.m.VBox (except simple but nothing explaining difference in names for objects and classes)?

In other words, what is functional difference in how these controls build containers for different flexible box layouts?

Comment: _The __HBox__ control builds the container for a horizontal flexible box layout._ _The __VBox__ control builds the container for a vertical flexible box layout_

Comment: Thanks, i already read in docs, what these controls build, however my question is not about what they build, but about how they build.

Comment: Are you seeking implementation of them ? If _Yes,_ then I am not the right person to ask mate ;( You can go through the parsed HTML to understand how they are implemented...They use `display : flex` and related css properties...

Comment: Rather, main (essential) difference in implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in the generated HTML.

The only difference is in the CSS properties for the Controls, for example `flex-direction`.

If you want to look at the code yourself, have a look at OpenUI5 on GitHub. You can find the relevant lines [here](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/themes/base/FlexBox.less#L43).

Comment: Indeed, sap.m.VBox sets style property "flex-direction" to "column", what means, that items are displayed vertically, as a column, but sap.m.HBox sets style property "flex-direction" to default value, i.e. "row", what means, that items are displayed horizontally, as a row.